# urllib2 header error: TypeError: sendall() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict

Tags: python, header, urllib2

```
def download(url):
    print url
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
    headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent }    
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return response
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm using the exact example from the docs:

http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html#headers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't using the exact example.  The example has:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
```

while you have:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers)
```

Because these are positional arguments, it's important that you keep them straight.  The second argument is a string of data, you need to supply that:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, "", headers)
```